# Identify the NFC tag or NFC-enabled device during transfer

Tags: nfc

I am very new to Android.

I want to identify which one is enabled NFC tag or NFC-enabled device.

Please provide the difference between NFC mode:

- card read/write
- P2P communication

Comment: Can you rephrase your first question? It's very difficult to understand.

Comment: From the [OpenNFC Features page](http://open-nfc.org/wp/home/features/): *Read/Write: Easy and transparent access to tags of different technologies is possible. P2P: Peer-to-peer functions allow easy exchange of information in different modes over the LLCP exchange format defined by the NFC Forum.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have a first question, or if I understand your first question. But, if you are looking for an app to read NFC tags, just search for "check nfc" in Google Play. There are a lot of apps there.

If you want to enable the NFC on a device, go to `Settings > Wireless & Networks > More... > NFC`. This is also how you check if the device can read NFC.

To answer your second question, please look at conor's answer in this question: [Is it possible to use Android Beam between an android device and another NFC device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813483/is-it-possible-to-use-android-beam-between-an-android-device-and-another-nfc-dev)